# Returning the number of results?

Tags: algolia

I'm looking to return the number of results found in an ajax fashion on Algolia instant search.

A little field saying something like "There are X number of results" and refines as the characters are typed.

I've read you utilise 'nbHits' but i'm unsure of how to go about it.. Being from a design background.

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [instantsearch.js stats widget](https://community.algolia.com/instantsearch.js/documentation/#stats) shows the number of results and speed of the search. If you don't want to use the widget, I believe you can still use `{{nbHits}}` inside of your template wherever you want the number to print.

Answer (score 1):

Very easy when you know how, Thanks for pointing me in the right direction Josh.

This works:

```
search.addWidget(
    instantsearch.widgets.stats({
        container: '.no-of-results'
    })
);
```